# Trying to understand Conditional test

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand conditional test and I'm just starting out using python was wondering I'm not see true or false in the terminal.

```
car = 'bmw'
car == 'bmw'
car = 'ford'
car == 'bmw'
```

supposed to state true or false in terminal

Comment: You'll probably want to print the result of the test. Like this: `print(car == 'bmw')`

Comment: yeah, supposed to display True or False in terminal. Try enter code into terminal line by line.

Comment: using print is useful if running a program from a file, but if just running on the Python interpreter console it isn't necessary.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the end part where he mentioned terminal. However, print technically would still work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> car = 'bmw'
>>> car == 'bmw'
True
>>> car == 'Ford'
False
```

Lines starting with ">>>" are the lines where I provided input, the other lines are Python's output. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An *assignment* (using the `=` operator) does not produce anything in Python. A comparison (using the `==` operator) does, so will show the result in the terminal:

```
>>> car = 'bmw'
>>> car == 'bmw'
True
>>> car = 'ford'
>>> car == 'bmw'
False
```

Note that `>>>` is the Python prompt, so text on those lines I have typed in. Text on lines without the prompt is generated by Python.

Comment: see what i was using was Geany and it doesn't work on there from what i can tell. So i switched to the actually terminal from python.org  and it worked fine. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Right. Geany is a text editor and as you say in your question, you need a terminal. Strictly speaking you just need a Python interpreter, but the interpreter is often run in a terminal. If this answer has helped, please use the tick or up arrow to promote it.